# how convert this C function pointer to a delphi function

Tags: c, delphi

There is a third-party C DLL, with Delphi 2007 development program (novice level), in the DLL header file, the function structure is more complex, there is a big god can give some ideas? C header file definition:

```
typedef int (*SetValueFunc)(const char* path, const char* value);
typedef const char* (*GetValueFunc)(const char* path);
typedef const ConfigNode* (*GetPropertysFunc)();

typedef struct  tagIProperty
{
    SetValueFunc     SetValue;
    GetValueFunc     GetValue;
    GetPropertysFunc GetPropertys;
}IProperty;
```

Call in C:

```
property->SetValue("0/baud_rate", "1000000")
```

I would be grateful if someone gave some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```pascal
type
  ConfigNode = record
    ...
  end;
  PConfigNode = ^ConfigNode;

  SetValueFunc = function(const path, value: PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl;
  GetValueFunc = function(const path: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar; cdecl;
  GetPropertysFunc = function: PConfigNode; cdecl;

  tagIProperty = record
    SetValue: SetValueFunc;
    GetValue: GetValueFunc;
    GetPropertys: GetPropertysFunc;
  end;
  IProperty = tagIProperty;
```

```pascal
var
  property: ^IProperty;
...
property := ...;
...
property.SetValue('0/baud_rate', '1000000');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent a little time trying to test.The problem has been solved